# How to stop a loop

Tags: php, cakephp, loops

My blog homepage works by looping through all the different blog categories and displays them

The only issue is I don't want some blog categorise to be displayed

How can I end the loop at a certain number?

HERE IS THE CODE:

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php  $category=$news_article_category->listCategory(); 
       foreach($category as $ids=>$name){ ?>
        <?php if($ids==1)
        {?>
         <h3 class="open"><?php echo h($name); ?></h3>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <h3><?php echo h($name); ?></h3>
        <?php }?>     
       <div>    
         <?php  $articles = $news_article->listlatestArticleByCat($ids);

       ?>
            <?php foreach($articles as $id => $title);
            $newVariable = str_replace(" ", "_", $title);  ?>
                <h2><a style="text-decoration:none; color:#333;" href="view_article.php?id=<?php  echo h($newVariable); ?>"><?php echo h($title); ?></a></h2>
             <p><?php $article = $news_article->getFromId($id);?>
             <?php $string = strip_tags($article['NewsArticle']['content'], '<p><br><strong><em><span><a>');
            $stringy=substr($string,0,350);
             /*pos varaiable defines the position of last occurance of Space in the string of 300 characters*/
             $pos=strripos($stringy," ");?>
           <?php /*Substring the string eliminating the last incomplete words*/ 
           echo substr($stringy,0,$pos); ?>
            <?php if($name=='Wills and Probate'){?>
             <a href="WillsProbate.php"> <img src="image/more_arrow.png" alt="" border="none"></a>
            <?php }elseif($name=='Landlord and Tenant') {?>
            <a href="LandlordTenant.php"> <img src="image/more_arrow.png" alt="" border="none"></a>
            <?php }elseif($name=='Divorce and Family') {?>
            <a href="DivorceFamily.php"> <img src="image/more_arrow.png" alt="" border="none"></a>
            <?php }elseif($name=='Commercial Property') {?>
            <a href="CommercialProperty.php"> <img src="image/more_arrow.png" alt="" border="none"></a>
            <?php }elseif($name=='Lease Extensions') {?>
            <a href="LeaseExtension.php"> <img src="image/more_arrow.png" alt="" border="none"></a>
            <?php }elseif($name=='Conveyancing') {?>
            <a href="conveyancing.php"> <img src="image/more_arrow.png" alt="" border="none"></a>

            <?php } ?>
           </p>
```

Comment: Typing the same question into [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How+to+stop+a+loop+php) would have given you the answer. Use `break` statements -- http://php.net/break/

Answer (score 1):

You can control a loop inside the loop using [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) and [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php):

```
$i = 0;
while ($i++) {
   if ($i == 5) {
       continue;
   }
   if ($i == 10) {
      break;
   }
   echo $i;
}
```

This will output `12346789`.

Answer (score 1):

You can exit any loop by using a "break."

[PHP break documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Also, try using more readable php when it's contained within html.

For example:

```
<?php if($ids==1): ?>
    <h3 class="open"><?=h($name) ?></h3>
<?php else: ?>
    <h3><?=h($name) ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Even better, don't contain it in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop a loop using the  **break** . If you have multiple nested fors, you can use something like  **go-to**  and when something inside a for happens, you can always go to the **break** for the initial for.

Finally, you can use  **exit**  and that will just stop the execution of the whole page right there.